# Fetching trending genre vs normal tracklist GET

Tags: ios, soundcloud

I'm hoping someone's figured this out since the web docs seem to be silent on this issue.

On iOS, we're using the SoundCloud web API to do various UI navigation once the user is logged in.  I've searched the API docs and it's not clear how to get a track list of currently "Trending" music, either for all genres or for a particular genre.  For example, to get a track list for a genre:

http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?limit=3genres=classical&client_id=XX

So what's the URL to access trending tracks?  It'd be great to support this in our app.

Thanks in advance!

Drew